# Can I add schema.org markup with JavaScript after page load?

Tags: seo, google, schema.org

My webpages show products. The product data (title, price, reviews, etc.) is fetched with an XHR and added to the DOM at run-time.

Does it make sense to add schema.org markup with JavaScript after the page load, or will Google completely ignore that markup?

Answer (score 1):

Google will mostly only crawl the static markup of your page.

Here's link to documentation -> https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org

> JSON-LD is supported for all Knowledge Graph features, sitelink search
>   boxes, Event Rich Snippets, and Recipe Rich Snippets; Google
>   recommends the use of JSON-LD for those features. For the remaining
>   Rich Snippets types and breadcrumbs, Google recommends the use of
>   microdata or RDFa.

Comment: This isn't true anymore, JSON-LD is now the recommended way to go according to the table in this link: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#structured-data-format